# CKEditor 5 - elementToAttribute multiple classes

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

```
  conversion.for('upcast').elementToAttribute({
    view: {
      name: 'span',
      classes: 'class1'
    ...
```

This way I create upcast conversion using elementToAttribute. Is there a way to add another class to perform this conversion on two spans, one having class1, second one having class2? Like this

```
  conversion.for('upcast').elementToAttribute({
    view: {
      name: 'span',
      classes: ['class1', 'class2']
    ...
```

I want to achieve having conversion on two spans

```
<span class="class1"
<span class="class2"
```

but the converion seems to be looking for one span that contains two classes class1 and class2. Do I have to create two conversions?

Answer (score 0):

Allright, class accepts also a regular expressions so I could write it like this
`classes: /^(class1|class2)$/`